# How to match only the first in vimregex

Tags: vim, neovim

`{{dockerhub | d('test')}}/{{kafka_topic_exporter_repository|default('kafka-topic-exporter') }}`

Here I want 2 mathes `{{ .* }}` But regex `{{\s*\(\S\+.*\S\+\)\s*}}` matches the entire line. Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vim supports non-greedy matching with the [`\{-}`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%7B-) operator:

```
{{\zs.\{-}\ze}}
```

this will match text inside the first braces: `dockerhub | d('test')`.

- `\zs` starts the match after `{{`.
- `\ze` ends the match before `}}`.
- If you need a capturing group replace `.\{-}` with `\(.\{-}\)`.